# How can I find the smallest value in a matrix that is greater than -Inf with R?

Tags: r, min, infinity

I have a matrix of values some of which are -Inf. How can I find the smallest value that is greater than -Inf?

Comment: is it acceptable for you to temporary set -Inf value as NA then call min(your.matrix) save your min value and again set NA as -Inf ?

Comment: I'd rather try and avoid it if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way:

```
foo <- matrix(c(1,2,-Inf,3),nrow=2,ncol=2)
min(foo[foo>-Inf])
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
min( foo[ is.finite(foo) ] #...
```